# What is the fastest way to search for names in a small database containing ca. 1.000.000 names?

Tags: sql, search, database-design

I need to determine, if a name is within a database or not (100% matching but name order is indifferent). The database contains ca. 1.000.000 names, result: yes/no. The server has 32 GB RAM, used only for this. How fast can a result come? Each name may contain up to 100 uppercase (A..Z) letters and/or numbers (0..9) and spaces, e.g. John Smith the 2nd. Many Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You mean you want to find 'John Smith the 2nd' by searching for the exact string, but also by searching for 'Smith the 2nd, John' (i.e. different order), but not when searching 'John Smith II' or just 'John Smith'?

Comment: The fastest way would be to parse the names and break them into words, store these in a separate table with a FK to the PK of the main table with clustered index on the name, then do simlar with the search criteria and then search individual search terms within this separate table.

Comment: Dear Thorsten, exactly as you wrote.

Comment: Dear Stu, many thanks. What is your estimation on a very fast hardware, how fast could this approximately happen? Please note, that I am not a developer or an IT professional person, I just wanted to check the fastest way as  our vendor claims it cannot take less than 1-2 seconds for one name

Comment: There are too many variables to give you any useful answer, you haven't even tagged your database platform. Given I just got a million search results from Google in <1 sec I would say with correct indexing there's no reason it couldn't be sub-second, especially if the data all resides in ram.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find `'John Smith the 2nd'` by searching for the exact string, but also by searching for `'Smith the 2nd, John'` (i.e. different order), but not when searching `'John Smith II'` or `'John Smith'` or `'John Michael Smith the 2nd'`.

This means a fast way to look for a name would be to store it in a normalized way (e.g. all parts ordered alphabetically, each separated from the next with one blank, dots and commas removed, all lower case). If you index that, the DBMS will find a name extremely fast via binary search.

How you do this depends on what your DBMS offers. In Oracle for instance I would write a database function to do the normalization on a name and write a function index. Thus the table just contains the normal name (`'John Smith the 2nd'`), but behind the scenes the DBMS has indexed the normalized one:

```
create index idx_name on mytable ( normalize_name(name) );

select * from mytable where normalize_name(name) = normalize_name(:input_name);
```

In another database you might use a computed column instead or even have a normal column that gets filled with a trigger and index that column. But the idea remains the same.

Without this approach the DBMS would have to read the whole table instead.  One million names are not that much, but reading them sequentially would still take significantly longer than binary search via an index.

Some databases offer full text search, but as you are only looking for exact matches (except for the word order), I expect my appraoch to be faster than that.